# Object Within Object - Arduino

Tags: class, object, arduino, nested

I'm designing a library for an IIR filter design. Long story short, a filter with an order of more than two, can be broken down into multiple 'sections' with order of two. I.e. 4-order filter = 2 x second-order filters.

I would like to create a class for a single-stage, second-order filter (already written). Then I would like to write another class that is able to break the full filter into multiple second-order filters.

… still following?!

Here is my code: I get an error saying "singleFilter not declared in this scope"

## IIR.h:

```
class master
{
public:
    master();
    int unsigned getHelloWorld();
};

class slave:
{
public:
    slave();
    int unsigned helloWorld();
};
```

## IIR.cpp

```
#include "IIR.h"

master::master()
{
    slave singleFilter;
}

int unsigned master::getHelloWorld()
{
    return singleFilter.hellowWorld();
}

slave::slave()
{

}

int unsigned slave::helloWorld()
{
    return 10;
}
```

## Arduino.ino:

```
#include <IIR.h>

master filter;

void setup()
{
    filer.getHelloWorld();
}

void loop()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable *singleFilter* is declared in the *master* constructor it is confined to function scope and cannot be referenced outside of the constructor.

Move *singleFilter* to the *master* class declaration to give it class scope and then it can be referenced in all *master* class methods.

```
class master
{
    slave singleFilter;
public:
    master();
    int unsigned getHelloWorld();
};
```